# Error Deserializando Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Codigo servidor

```
public class TestController: ApiController
{

    public string Get()
    {

        Users user = new Users
        {
            name = "Hola",
            surname = "Mundo"
        };
        var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Codigo Cliente

```
        public static async void GetResponse()
    {
        HttpClient a = new HttpClient();

        var response = await a.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:57740/api/test");

        Users u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(response);
        Console.WriteLine(u.name);


    }
```

El string que obtengo en cliente es:

`"\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Hola\\\",\\\"surname\\\":\\\"Mundo\\\"}\""`

Tengo un error a la hora de Deserializar objeto en cliente, imagino que es por que recibo contrabarras de más. ¿Estoy enviando mal el json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web api serializa los objeto a json por defecto por lo que estas serializando un json que ya fue serializado, por eso las barras.

Intenta retornando el objeto en si en vez del string:

```
public User GetUser()
{
  var user = new User { Name = "hola" , surname = "Mundo" };
  return user;
}
```

Ten encuenta que si lo ejecutas por el navegador, probablemente te mostrara un el objeto en formato xml en vez de json. Esto es por el `content-type="text/html"` que por defecto que los navegadores envian. Si haces una peticion con ajax, te retorna un json.

Comment: Era eso,
Muchisimas gracias!